# python-dotenv fails to import PRIVATE_KEY from .env file: "Cannot convert None of type <class 'NoneType'> to bytes"

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, dotenv

I am learning solidity and when I use python-dotenv to import my PRIVATE_KEY from a .env file,
`export PRIVATE_KEY = 0xd6a5ea3d2c97b1dd03fd1b9c447e36791522135136665f23b0c08c6395f66d7a`
it imports it as `None` and throws an error.

```
from solcx import compile_standard
import json
from web3 import Web3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

# Compile Our Solidity

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    }
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

# get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

# get abi
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

# for connecting to ganache
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"))
chain_id = 1337
my_address = "0xDFb3e342C0A8F724bfA72e5F2773a12748977f46"
private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")

# Create the contract in python
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)

# Get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)

# 1. Build a transaction
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
    }
)
# 2. Sign a transaction
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)

# 3. Send a transaction
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

[image: This error]
Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is importing dotenv but not actually using it. You must actually call `load_dotenv()`, not just import it.

Even after calling `load_dotenv()` , you may get the same error while compiling. Well, this is due to the error which may be present in your ".env" file between the export statement and the variable used for Private Key declaration.

It(VS Code) may guide you to add a word 'const' in between them, by which the variable will be declared as a constant.
But, leave the error as-it-is and compile, Your code will surely compile.

Answer (score 1):

Even after calling `load_dotenv()` , you may get the same error while compiling. Well, this is due to the error which may be present in your ".env" file between the export statement and the variable used for Private Key declaration.

It(VS Code) may guide you to add a word 'const' in between them, by which the variable will be declared as a constant.
But, leave the error as-it-is and compile, Your code will surely compile.